# Storing object expressions that continuously evaluate in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

Hi All

I ran into a bit of an unexpected issue today when building a prototype e-commerce site. Specifically, I have a method that is set to take user input and apply a discount based on:

1). Whether or not the code is correct (this is represented by object keys in my code).

2). Whether the user's current total meets some minimum criteria (represented by $scope.total comparisons).

Here's the code I'm using to achieve this:

```
$scope.processDiscount = function(code) {
 var discountInfo = {
   'FIVE': {
     condition: true,
     discount: 5
   },
   'TEN': {
     condition: $scope.total > 50,
     discount: 10
   },
   'FIFTEEN': {
     condition: $scope.total > 75 && $scope.reviewCartCategories('Men\'s Footwear', 'Women\'s Footwear'),
     discount: 15
   }
 };
 for (var key in discountInfo) {
   if (code === key && discountInfo[key].condition) {
     $scope.applyDiscount(discountInfo, key);
   };
 };
};
```

The issue is that I really don't like having this mammoth object defined inside the method. I initially tried assigning it to a variable on the $scope, however I found that this would just set the value once, i.e. whenever a user added an item to their cart and therefore increased the 'total' price, this wouldn't be reflected in the $scope variable.

Since $scope.total is initially set to 0 when my controller loads, it would always hold this value.

Is there a better way of handling this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I belive it´s a good case to use [**Filters**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

**Code**

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .filter('discount', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input * 0.5;
    };
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;
  }]);
```

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="total"/>
    {{ total | discount }}
</body>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/umFdgTnBTImy7OaDQ2dw?p=preview)

^ **Updated to your Question**

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="total"/>
    discount = {{ total | discount }}
    total with discount = {{ total - (total |discount) }}
</body>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .filter('discount', function() {
    return function(input) {
      switch(true){
        case (input > 50):
          return input * 0.1;
          break;
        case (input > 75):
          return input * 0.15;
          break;
        default:
          return input * 0.05;
          break;
      }
      return 0;
    };
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;
  }]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xBGTEnWwWshwXgmfqKe2?p=preview)

^ **Edit**

I Noticed now your var code you can send extra param like this

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="total"/>
    discount = {{ total | discount:'FIVE'}}
    total with discount = {{ total - (total|discount:'FIVE') }}
</body>
```

And receive them like this

**CODE**

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .filter('discount', function() {
    return function(input, code) {
      switch(true){
        case (code == 'FIVE'):
          return input * 0.05;
          break;
        case (input > 50 && code == 'TEN'):
          return input * 0.1;
          break;
        case (input > 75 && code == 'FIFTEEN'):
          return input * 0.15;
          break;
        default:
          return 0;
          break;
      }
      return 0;
    };
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 0;
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to keep most of my code inside the controller but I think if I inject $filter into my controller and set up a function that calls the filter then this could be a nifty solution. Going to give it a whirl!

Comment: Humm. for me it´is the oposity, the most code i can remove from controllers and divide them in small trunks the better. Btw @Allan do you have to have the logic of discounts in the frontend, maybe it´s a good idea to call a backend api to calculate the discounts. Or at least be sure to validate the discounts on submit server side :)

Comment: I ended up creating the discount logic in both my controller and a factory that stores the conditions/discount amounts similar to what you suggested doing with the filter and it's actually worked out quite nicely.

A backend api call would have been ideal but unfortunately I didn't have enough time to explore that in too much detail. Nonetheless your suggestion was really helpful so thank you :)